# How to Solve 403 Error in Spring Boot Post Request

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

I am newbie in spring boot rest services. I have developed some rest api in spring boot using maven project.

I have successfully developed **Get** and **Post** Api. My **GET** Method working properly in postman and mobile. **when i am trying to hit post method from postman its working properly but from mobile its gives 403 forbidden error.**

This is my Configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = te
spring.datasource.password = test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Please Suggest me how to solve error.

[image]

Comment: Are you sending any header with postman? I think that you are sending a token in order to authenticate the request.
Are you sending this token on POST from your mobile device?

Comment: Please add details of your spring-boot configuration.

Comment: i am sending  only Content type from postman and mobile @desoss

Comment: please attach the logs, spring has surprisingly readable error messages in logs ;)

Comment: This is my configurations: #spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.4.2/maha?useSSL=false
#spring.datasource.username = test
#spring.datasource.password = test@123
#
#
### Hibernate Properties
## The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
#
## Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update @JannikWeichert

Comment: I'm not aware of your configuration, but if on your device you are sending the same headers, URI and HttpMethod of postman, it must work.
(Uri is correct, right? :D)

Comment: Please edit your question und use correct formats. Otherwise it's not readable. Additionally please add your WebConfiguration.

Comment: i have updated my question@JannikWeichert

Comment: attach screenshot from postman and from the program you use on your mobile. There must be some difference. It is possible that requests don't work from outside localhost (dev security settings) but then `GET` wouldn't work either

Comment: Get is working  properly in mobile and postman

Comment: I know, please attach the screenshots

Answer (score 259, accepted):

you have to disable csrf Protection because it is enabled by default in spring security: here you can see code that allow cors origin.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Comment: disabling csrf made my POST requests successful! what a relief.

Comment: I had the same situation combined with JWT based authentication. This solution worked for me one addition:  I had to allow "OPTIONS" request to pass without JWT in Authorization header.

Comment: Why disabling csrf allowed post method?

Comment: @Ezzat Eissa  - Disabling `csrf` certainly works. But this also makes our APIs vulnerable, isn't it? If so how do make sure that csrf token is configured both from server and client side?

Comment: This answer should come with some warning. There are some good reasons to keep csrf enabled. To work with csrf enabled: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/html5/#csrf

Comment: Mentioning comment from java doc : `Keep in mind however that theCORS spec does not allow "*" when allowCredentials is set to true and as of 5.3 that combinationis rejected in favor of using allowedOriginPatterns instead. `

Comment: Spring 6 update, `http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)`

Answer (score 12):

In Spring Security Cross-site check is by default enable, we need to disable it by creating a separate class to stop cross-checking.

```java
package com.baba.jaxws;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

     @Override
    //we have stopped the csrf to make post method work
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Possible causes:

1. Requests done from postman are different to the one done from mobile (uri, method, headers)
2. Invalid token
3. CORS (read something about it, google is full of articles) add @CrossOrigin annotation to your controller.
4. mobile app is doing an OPTION request before performing the POST, and you block OPTION requests.  If also from postman the OPTION requests are blocked, add the property *spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true*. Moreover, in case you are using spring security, you have to explicitly allow OPTION requests also for it.

Comment: can you  please tell me how to add option request  ?@desoss

Comment: I've updated point 4... let me know if with spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true it works.

Comment: yes i am trying with that. i will let you know if worked

Comment: Yes, you are right - the POST request from Postman was considered CORS, but just wondering why the GET requests from Postman were going through even though CORS is disabled?

Answer (score 7):

CSRF is enabled by default in Spring Security. Having this enabled ensures a 403 error on HTTP requests that would change (object) states.
For more information please visit: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/html5/#csrf

It is possible to disable CSRF in the Spring Security. However, it is enabled by default (convention over configuration) and for a good reason. This is also explained in the link provided to Spring's Security.

A working example, using Thymeleaf, might be:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
</head>
```

**JS**

```
function postExample() {
    let token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    let header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    let data = {username: "", password: "", firstname: "", lastname: ""};

    // Object key string interpolation by {[header]:token} works with ES6
    fetch(window.location+"/addnote", {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
            [header]: token,
            "charset": "UTF-8",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

**CONTROLLER** per request of @mahmoud-magdy

```
@PostMapping("/addnote")
public Long addNote(@RequestBody() String data) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JSONAddNote json = gson.fromJson(data, JSONAddNote.class);
    return <service>.addNote(json.username, json....);
}

class JSONAddNote {
    public String username;
    public String ...etc
}
```

Or a more direct **CONTROLLER**:

```
@PostMapping("/addnote")
public Long addNote(@RequestBody Data data) {
    return <service>.addNote(data);
}

class Data {
    public String username;
    public String ...etc
}
```

Comment: could you please mention the last part in controller how to retrieve the data

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this by using:

```
<form th:action="@{url}" method="post">
```

Instead of:

```
<form action="url" method="post">
```

It seems the th:action tag does url rewriting to enable csrf validation.

Comment: Indeed indeed indeed! This is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689803/6351897) : "_After some investigation I've found out that only forms that were using 'th:action' attribute (not plain 'action') had the csrf token injected._"

Comment: This is the solution. I don't understand how disabling CSRF protection is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

To build on the accepted answer

Many HTTP client libraries (eg Axios) implicitly set a `Content-Type: JSON` header for POST requests. In my case, I forgot to allow that header causing only POSTS to fail.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    ...
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type"); // <- ALLOW THIS HEADER 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `Content-Type: application/json` instead of `Content-Type: JSON`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is related to this question if you are deploying to Open/WAS Liberty server.

If so, you might get 403 error even though your code works perfectly fine if deploying to embedded Tomcat that comes with Spring boot.

Liberty does not read (or considers) your

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myapi/v1
```

that you set in your **application.properties** or **application.yml** file for some reason.  Or, it just overwrites it, not sure.  So, the above `context-path` will work just fine if deployment in Spring Boot embeded  Tomcat container.

However, when you deploy it to OpenLiberty/WASLiberty, you might find that your endpoints will stop working and you get 403 and/or 404 errors.

In my example, I have api where I have `/auth` endpoint in my WebSecurityConfiguration class:

```
//Customize the /login url to overwrite the Spring default provided /login url.
private AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    // This works fine on embedded tomcat, but not in Liberty where it returns 403.  
    // To fix, in server.xml <appllication> block, add 
    // <application context-root="/myapi/v1" ... and then both
    // auth and other endpoints will work fine in Liberty.
    filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/auth"); 
    // This is temporary "fix" that creates rather more issues, as it 
    // works fine with Tomcat but fails in Liberty and all other
    // endpoints still return 404
    //filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/v1/auth"); 
    return filter;
}
```

Based on the above `context-path`, on Tomcat, it becomes `/myapi/v1/auth` while on Liberty, it ends up being just `/myapi/auth` which is wrong.  I think what Liberty does, it will just take the name of the api and add to it the endpoint, therefore ignoring the versioning.

As a result of this, `AntPathRequestMatcher` class `matches()` method will result in a non-matching `/auth` end point and you will get 403 error.  And the other endpoints will result in 404 error.

**SOLUTION**

In your **application.properties**, leave

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myapi/v1
```

, this will be picked up by embedded Tomcat and your app will continue to work as expected.

In your **server.xml** configuration for Open/WAS Liberty, add **matching** context-root to the  section like:

```xml
<application context-root="/myapi/v1" id="myapi" location="location\of\your\myapi-0.0.1.war" name="myapi" type="war">
```

, this will be picked up by Open/WASLiberty and your app will continue to work as expected on Liberty container as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is for those that like me came here because they were writing post tests and encountered 403 instead of any expected errors (depending on code state).

Instead of disabling csrf one can obtain the CSRF token so that you can use it in the header of the call, much like how it works with a form in Thymeleaf.

With tests you just add `with(csrf())` to the call like here

```
mvc.perform(post("/")
.with(csrf()) //CSRF token is sent
.contentType("application/json")
.content(""))
.andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

This way you can move ahead without disabling CSRF, much like how it likely will work in the production code. There are also other options as you can read in the [Testing with CSRF Protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/csrf.html) documentation.

If you later need to make this present also in your actual Thymeleaf form you can add csrf to it as a hidden type:

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the 403 Forbidden error you're encountering might be related to Spring Security. If your GET requests are working fine but POST requests are failing, there might be some configuration blocking mobile requests.
One solution is to review your Spring Security configuration. If you are not using security features extensively, you might consider removing the spring-boot-starter-security dependency altogether. However, if you need security, follow these steps to configure it properly

1. Step:

Check your security configuration class (if you have one) that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/your-endpoint").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin().and()
        .httpBasic();
   }
}
```

2. Step

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS):
If your mobile app is running on a different domain, ensure that you have proper CORS configuration to allow requests from that domain.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://your-mobile-app-domain.com")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?