# Problem with Spring Boot Security and CORS when it comes to POST requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to secure a REST service for personal use and used as a backed for an Angular app using method to method security like this.

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'Player', 'expenseReport.allowed')")
    @GetMapping(value = "editplayer")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = crossorg)
    public Player getEditPlayerAuthorize(@RequestParam Long id){
        return fetcher.fetchPlayer(id);
    }
```

The @CrossOrigin annotation works perfectly where, but when I try the same on a POST request it fails because of CORS:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "login", produces = "application/json")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = crossorg)
    public Login attemptLogin(@RequestBody Login payload) {        
        return handler.attemptLogin(payload);
    }
```

So I guess Spring Boot security is somehow interfering in this, but I see no solution why this should affect only POST requests? They worked fine before I added Spring Boot Security.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the proper url for @CrossOrigin? (For eg. localhost url of front end).
2. default enabled csrf may have to be disabled.

refer this [How to Solve 403 Error in Spring Boot Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486314/how-to-solve-403-error-in-spring-boot-post-request)

Request Experts to help resolve this.

Comment: One the one hand, your comment did not solve my situation, BUT i solved that situation myself, but when I had there was a new problem, that your comment fixed. I had disabled by accident, so thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome.    I too was getting 403 error for Post requests. I added this and resolved the issue.  Hope this may help someone who face the same issue.                                                                                                                            @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }